# Fade In Fade Out with Delay using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, delay, fadein, fadeout

let me start by saying that I am a novice developer (maybe even below that), so, I apologize if I do not explain myself well.

I am trying to get several customer reviews about our product to splash onto the screen (FadeIn1, delay, FadeOut1), (FadeIn2, delay, FadeOut2) etc. I can get the fade-in and fade-out to work individually but I can't seem to get them to work together. The below code only fades it out. Can some one please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance...

```css
/* keyframes that tell the start state and the end state of our object */
 
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; }}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; }}
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; }}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut { from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; }}
@-moz-keyframes fadeOut { from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; }}
@keyframes fadeOut { from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; }}
 
.fade-in {
 opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
 -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
 -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
 animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
  
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
 -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
 animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
 -moz-animation-duration:1s;
 animation-duration:1s;
}

.fade-out {
 opacity:1;  /* make things visible upon start */
 -webkit-animation:fadeOut ease-out 1;  /* call keyframe named fadeOut, use animattion ease-out and repeat it only 1 time */
 -moz-animation:fadeOut ease-out 1;
 animation:fadeOut ease-out 1;
 
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 0)*/
 -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
 animation-fill-mode:forwards;
 
 -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
 -moz-animation-duration:1s;
 animation-duration:1s;
 
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
 animation-delay: 3s;
}
 
.fade-in.fade-out.one {
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
-moz-animation-delay: 0.7s;
animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
 
.fade-in.fade-out.two {
-webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
-moz-animation-delay:1.2s;
animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
 
.fade-in.fade-out.three {
-webkit-animation-delay: 1.6s;
-moz-animation-delay: 1.6s;
animation-delay: 1.6s;
}
 
/*---basic box ---*/
.box{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #333;
background: #999;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="box fade-in fade-out one">
       look at me fade in and out
</div>
 
<div class="box fade-in fade-out two">
       i can fade too!
</div>
 
<div class="box fade-in fade-out three">
       i can fade three!
</div>
 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original code is very close.  Building upon the @ILoveCSS answer and your use of animation delay, I think this is the effect you are looking for:

```css
@keyframes fade {
   0% { opacity: 0 }
  20% { opacity: 1 } /* 20% of 5 seconds = 1 second */
  80% { opacity: 1 }
  100% { opacity: 0 }
}
 
.fade {
  opacity:0;
  animation: fade ease-in-out 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fade:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 0.25s; }
.fade:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 0.5s; }

.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="box fade">Box 1</div>
<div class="box fade">Box 2</div>
<div class="box fade">Box 3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this worked for me   I added `infinite` in the animate property to make it loop

Answer (score 0):

You can **simplify** the animation by using **% frames** instead.

You can control the speed of the animation under the `.box` animation selector.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes myfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes myfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes myfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #999;
  animation: myfade 8s;
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box fade-in fade-out one">
    look at me fade in and out
  </div>
  <div class="box fade-in fade-out two">
    i can fade too!
  </div>
  <div class="box fade-in fade-out three">
    i can fade three!
  </div>
</body>
```